# Expandable mat-table on mat-icon-button click

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, mat-table

I implemented the following functionality (expand row details, when you click on the row it opens up its details) in my mat-table:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-wervgn?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

But this it is opening the detail div wherever I click on the row. I would like to expend/open up or collapse only on mat-icon expand_more/expand_less click.

I tried to call onToggleChange on the button click, yet it did not work.

If anyone could help me with that.

Thanks for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your example and i think i achieved the expected behaviour. Basically i used the ViewChildren view query to get all detail-row directive instances an called the toggle function on icon click.
Have a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-asu1zv?file=app%2Fcdk-detail-row.directive.ts

Comment: thank you very much. That is exactly what I have been trying to do and did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works perfectly, it only misses the logic to close the previous opened row when you open a new one.

You can easily achieve this by looping over view query and triggering the onToggleChange on each row if they are currently opened.

Something like this:

```
  expand(element: any) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.detailRows.length; i++) {
      const openedRow = this.detailRows.find(x => x.row == i)
      if (openedRow?.expended) {
        this.onToggleChange(openedRow?.row);
      }
    }

    const detail = this.detailRows.find(x => x.row == element);
    detail?.toggle();
  }
```